# 2 dimension array of objects in class

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to declare a 2d array of objects  as a property in a class , but i am receiving an error : array has incomplete element type.

```
@property RoundObj *rounds[][];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare 2 dimensional arrays in that way.

You should declare it like:

```
@property RoundObj __autoreleasing **rounds; // Dynamic
```

But instead of doing this, I would suggest using `NSMutableArray`. You can add another `NSMutableArray` to another one and can achieve 2 dimensional array like mechanism. It's much better way.

Comment: gives an error (Pointer to non-const type 'RoundObj *' with no explicit ownership)

Comment: @TarekMowafy: forgot to add `__autoreleasing`. Check that now

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your array with it's capacity. You also need to set it as an instance variable and not a property

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    RoundObj *rounds[9][9];
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someUnrelatedString;

@end
```

Alternatively, you could nest `NSMutableArray`s in more arrays

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arr;
...
_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
     NSMutableArray *newArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     [arr addObject:newArr];
 }
```

Comment: but the capacity is dynamic

Comment: Check my updated answer. Your RoundObjs would go into each `newArr`

Answer (score 0):

Using NSArrays does not enforce a particular type but can be used to create multidimensional arrays *by convention*. I use comments to indicate what the expected structure is.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rounds; //of NSArray* of RoundObj*
```